# distcp local file to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mapr, distcp

I have 1 Gb file on local file system /tmp/dist_testfle

I can copy it it: `hadoop fs -put file:///tmp/dist_testfile maprfs:///`

But cannot *distcp* it. Command `hadoop distcp file:///tmp/dist_testfile maprfs:///`
it thorws FileNotFoundException

```
20/05/19 15:57:40 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job-id: job_1588609058920_0136
20/05/19 15:57:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1588609058920_0136
20/05/19 15:57:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1588609058920_0136 running in uber mode : false
20/05/19 15:57:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
20/05/19 15:57:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1588609058920_0136_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand$CopyReadException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:///tmp/dist_testfile does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand$CopyReadException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:///tmp/dist_testfile does not exist
    ... 10 more
```

Why it throws the Exception. At last, how to copy file with distcp from local FS to hadoop?

Comment: DistCp is for copying files from one cluster to another cluster, not for copying from local to hadoop.

Comment: Try using instead "hfs dfs -copyFromLocal local_path clutter_path" command.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough information in the question to be sure of giving you a complete answer. In particular, it isn't quite clear whether your MapR cluster is remote from the place where your local data is.

If we pull back a bit from the focus on distcp for a moment, the normal way to copy a file from a local file store into a MapR system doesn't use hadoop commands at all. Those commands tend to be very slow to start and eat an enormous amount of memory to complicate simple tasks. Thus, I might do this to copy a file

`cp /tmp/dist_testfile /mapr/metrics-cluster/home/tdunning/tmp-dir`

This has a few subtleties to it. First, we are using ordinary Linux commands. We could have used rsync as well to do an incremental copy. This is great for relatively small files (less than several GB) because the limited transfer rate for a single process (usually less than 2GB/s) is offset by the vastly faster startup time. Second, this presumes that we have mounted the MapR file system on the local machine. This could be done using NFS or the POSIX driver (the latter is better, usually). Third, I have named the cluster I want to transfer to in the command (metrics-cluster). If configured to allow access, this could have been any cluster that I can have see, near or far.

This is all well and good. It is often far better to use this style than to use more elaborate tool. The same goes for writing simple programs, or even complex programs that will run under Kubernetes.

If, on the other hand, what you want is not so much to transfer a single file, but to debug how to make distcp to work, we have a different kettle of fish.

The first step in debugging distcp is to determine some things

a) does distcp have access to the MapR jars that provide an HDFS implementation that can access MapR FS? The simplest way to make this happen is to use the MapR-provided distcp since that comes with everything pre-integrated. Because `hadoop fs` commands seem to work, it appears that you have a valid MapR installation, but it is possible you have distcp from outside that installation.

b) is the local machine configured correctly to access the cluster you want to write to? Again, given that the `hadoop fs` command works, it seems that you do.

c) are the arguments to distcp exactly correct. This is, in my experience, the most common problem. The argument parsing in various hadoop commands like distcp is kind of notoriously brittle. Part of that is the code, but part of that is due to the fact that simple things like the tab key for file completion depends on the shell having access to files via normal path names. That blows apart when you start including the file system scheme. I can't comment on your command syntax very much since I almost never use distcp (I use simpler methods), but I can say that I have heard of a number of users having difficulty getting it to work as expected. Perhaps holding your mouth in just the right way is the answer (that was a joke, btw).

d) finally, can you verify that the local file system is configured correctly in your Hadoop configuration files? I have had users who changed file: to local: and then they got very confused.